# accessing shared variable in wait_event_timeout linux interface

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, race-condition, kernel

`wait_event_timeout` can be used to put a thread to sleep for specified time or until some condition becomes true.
I am facing a situation where this condition is a shared variable.

```
ret = wait_event_timeout(SLEEP_Q,shared_vaible == 1,TIME_TO_SLEEP);
```

Before calling this I have to let go of the `spinlock` used to access the shared variable.

So my question is does the correctness get compromised since the shared variable is read without using a lock ?
Does the kernel ensure that such conditions in `wait_event` interface dont have race conditions?

Answer (score 3):

If the variable is small enough that it can be updated atomically, and if all updates do indeed happen atomically (with something like `ACCESS_ONCE(shared_variable) = 1;`), then you can use the code in the question.

Otherwise, you have to get the lock while reading the variable.
The best way to do this would be to create a simple helper function:

```c
ret = wait_event_timeout(SLEEP_Q, read_shared_variable() == 1, TIME_TO_SLEEP);
```